# AGENT_ERROR_INVALID_EVENT_TYPE when testing an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin. When testing it, I sometimes encounter the following error:

```
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_INVALID_EVENT_TYPE(204): ExceptionOccurred [../../../src/share/back/eventHelper.c:808]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP ExceptionOccurred, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_INVALID_EVENT_TYPE(204)
```

Which immediately kills the running eclipse instance (not the eclipse host).

Does anyone know what can lead to this error? I suspect some multithreading shenanigans, but it's not easy pinpointing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out this was the result of a wayward `Thread.stop()` method invoked when running eclipse in debug mode. This didn't happen in run mode, only in debug mode, and it no longer appeared after removing the `stop()` method.

I guess [it is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) for a good reason!

Comment: It happens for me too when I tried to stop() synchronized threads which are in wait() state and it's gone after I switched to interrupt().

Answer (score -1):

You are passing wrong arguments to the jvm. You can try first by removing all the options and then adding one by one to find out which one causes the error

Comment: You mean, as in the JVM startup arguments?

Comment: Yes. I guess you are trying to debug/profile you Eclipse and passing on the wrong arguments for that